# Scapy DNS request malformed only with TCP

Tags: python, tcp, dns, scapy

I use scapy and python to build my DNS request. No problem for UDP request but when I want to use TCP (**with exactly the same request that I use with UDP**), Wireshark say that my DNS request are malformed.

Here my python code:

```
from scapy.all import *
ip=IP(dst="130.104.254.1")
dns = DNS(rd=1, qd=DNSQR(qname = "google.be", qtype="A"))


SYN=ip/TCP(sport=RandNum(1024,65535), dport=53, flags="S", seq=42)
SYNACK=sr1(SYN)

ACK=ip/TCP(sport=SYNACK.dport, dport=53, flags="A", seq=SYNACK.ack, ack=SYNACK.seq + 1)
send(ACK)

DNSRequest = ip/TCP(sport=SYNACK.dport, dport=53, flags="PA", seq=SYNACK.ack, ack=SYNACK.seq + 1) / dns
DNSReply = sr1(DNSRequest, timeout = 1)
```

The Three Way Handshake are fully completed before I send my request.

[image: Here my wireshark error]

Thank you very much !

Comment: My bet is that somehow you are sending a DNS request in UDP format over TCP. That won't work because there's no way to determine the length of the request. (In UDP, the datagram size will tell you the length of the request. But TCP does not preserve application message boundaries, so that won't work.)

Comment: You win your bet ! Thank you very much David.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more research I found in the RFC 1035 :

> 4.2.2. TCP usage
>
> Messages sent over TCP connections use server port 53 (decimal). The
>   message is prefixed with a two byte length field which gives the
>   message length, excluding the two byte length field. This length field
>   allows the low-level processing to assemble a complete message before
>   beginning to parse it.

So the solution is in the code below :

```
from scapy.all import *

ip=IP(dst="216.239.32.10")

request = DNS(rd=1, qd=DNSQR(qname = "google.be", qtype="A")) #size = 27(dec) = 1b (hex)
twoBytesRequestSize = "\x00\x1b" #BIG ENDIAN
completeRequest = str(request) + twoBytesRequestSize

SYN=ip/TCP(sport=RandNum(1024,65535), dport=53, flags="S", seq=42)
SYNACK=sr1(SYN)

ACK=ip/TCP(sport=SYNACK.dport, dport=53, flags="A", seq=SYNACK.ack, ack=SYNACK.seq + 1)
send(ACK)

DNSRequest = ip/TCP(sport=SYNACK.dport, dport=53, flags="PA", seq=SYNACK.ack, ack=SYNACK.seq + 1) / completeRequest
DNSReply = sr1(DNSRequest, timeout = 1)
```